# Qual è la differenza tra gli aggettivi "intellettuale" e "intellettivo"?

Tags: adjectives, difference, vocabulary

Per esempio, si dice *È un'attività intellettualmente stimolante* oppure *intellettivamente stimolante*? Si dice *capacità intellettive* o *intellettuali*? Qual è la differenza?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Intellettivo"** si riferisce alla capacità fisica del cervello e della mente di ragionare: infatti si dice "quoziente intellettivo". 
Si dice *"capacità intellettive"* se vuoi indicare le capacità di ragionamento di qualcuno. Ad esempio nella frase *"Le capacità intellettive del bambino sono già elevate due anni"*. O anche per un animale: *"Le capacità intellettive di una scimmia sono considerevoli"* (considerevoli = molto alte).

***"Intellettuale"*** può essere un sostantivo che indica un gruppo di persone di alta cultura e istruzione, che si occupano di studi in qualche campo (politica, filosofia, sociologia...) come in *"Gli intellettuali di sinistra si sono schierati contro la proposta di legge"*.

Come avverbio:
*"È un'attività intellettualmente stimolante"* significa che stimola la tua personale riflessione su un argomento, e che l'attività è interessante a livello culturale e di pensiero. È più una cosa astratta.

Non è corretto dire "intellettivamente stimolante", perchè così ti riferiresti al "cervello" e alle sue funzioni.

Answer (score 4):

**Intellettuale** è riferito all’intelletto, che concerne l’intelletto e la sua attività, di solito in contrapposizione al sentimento, alla fantasia, alla volontà, al senso morale. Anche inteso come complesso delle facoltà mentali e dell’attività culturale.

Ad esempio si dice "*proprietà intellettuale*", o nel tuo caso è corretto dire "*attività intellettualmente stimolante*".

**Intellettivo** riguarda l’attività dell’intelletto, la capacità d’intendere con l’intelletto.

Ad esempio si dice "*quoziente intellettivo*" (il QI), o nel tuo caso è corretto dire "*capacità intellettive*".

Fonti: [intellettuale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intellettuale/) e [intellettivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intellettivo/).

Comment: Avevo già letto le definizioni della Treccani, non mi hanno aiutato. Da quanto dice quel vocabolario i due termini mi sembrano essere sinonimi.

Comment: No non lo sono, in parole povere *intellettuale* definisce un'attività culturale o comunque qualcosa che richiede il pensiero e l'interpretazione da parte della mente. Invece *intellettivo* si riferisce alla capacità di ragionare, intendere e comprendere.